# Docker multiple Volume-driver

Tags: docker

Is it possible with Docker 1.8+ to specify different volume-drivers for different volumes in one container?

So I can use with one volume the default driver for local storage and one different with NFS or something?

Except mounting the host system with an NFS folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible, only one driver is used for the contener as decribed in the man page of docker 1.11

```
--volume-driver=""
     Container's volume driver. This driver creates volumes specified either from
     a Dockerfile's VOLUME instruction or from the docker run -v flag.
     See docker-volume-create(1) for full details.
```

and from a [Docker Member citation from docker's github](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16069#issuecomment-138297804)

Answer (score 5):

Starting with **Docker 17.05.0-ce**, you can use the `--mount` option with `docker run`, which makes using different volume drivers easier. For example:

```
docker run -ti \
  --mount volume-driver=convoy,src=volume-name1,target=/mnt/vol1 \
  --mount volume-driver=local,src=volume-name2,target=/mnt/vol2 \
  ubuntu bash
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems not to be possible indeed but there is a trick to make it work with one command line ([from the same Docker Member post](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16069)) :

```
docker run -d \
    -v $(docker volume create --driver=flocker --name=volumename):/data \
    -v $(docker volume create --driver=foobar --name=something):/somewhere \
    myimage
```